# Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing from local storage through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, local-storage

Here I am trying to write a function which retrieves my data from local storage but it's coming with an error of *`UNEXPECTED END OF JSON INPUT`*.

```
function saveBookmark(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //Get form values
  var siteName = document.getElementById('siteName').value;
  var siteUrl = document.getElementById('siteUrl').value;
  var bookmark = {
    name: siteName,
    url: siteUrl
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') == null) {
    var bookmarks = [];
    //add to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    //set to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  } else {
    //fetch bookmarks from local strorage
    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks')); 

    //add bookmark to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    //reset back to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }

}
```

I can't parse my array back to json ,i.e

```
 var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
```

what could be the possible solution ?

Comment: How big is your bookmarks array? It is possible that you are exceeding the maximum storage space you have allocated

Comment: @RobM. it's only of 2 elements , lemme check, may be u r right

Comment: @RobM. hey rob actually i was doing this project with watching its tutorial,, so the one who is teaching has his code working fine and its the same code

Comment: How often are you calling this? What event is it being run from?

Comment: It's not reaching the storage limit

Comment: The problem was in local storage as when data was being stored and i manipulated the data , the syntax was going wrong like the last bracket was missing all the time. Now i solved it.